# Не выводятся картинки согласно условию скрипта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Приветствую. Есть картинки с описанием, которые на странице могут быть разной длины. Хочу к не стандартным размерам картинок со стандартным описанием (стандартные равны 346) применить условие, но не получается вот что: если использовать размер иной чем 346, то на выходе получаются все картинки с описанием, причем как со стандартным размером 346, так и с любым другим (это четко видно в консоли), но если установить 346, то ни выводится ни одна! в консоли - что не так?

```js
 $('.wp-post-image').each(function(i) {
   if ($('.wp-post-image').height() + $('.product-section h3').height() != 346) {
     var height = $('.wp-post-image').eq(i).height() + $('.product-section h3').eq(i).height();
     var heighth3 = $('.product-section h3').eq(i).text();
     console.log(height);
     console.log(heighth3);
   }
 });
```

```css
.thumbnail-container img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-frame ">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="front">
        <img src="#" class="wp-post-image" alt="">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--/ .thumbnail-container-->
  <div class="content-description">
    <div class="product-section">
      <h3><a href="#">Название продукта...</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

По крайней мере, одну ошибку вижу:

```
$('.wp-post-image').height() + $('.product-section h3').height()
```

Данная штука хавает значения не текущего элемента (ибо без eq() ), а последнего в наборе (или 1го - не помню эту особенность jquery). В общем, получается, "если последнее изображение из набора не равно 346...

Попробуй вот так:

```
 $('.wp-post-image').each(function(i) {

    var heighth3 = $('.product-section h3').eq(i).height();  //перенес в начало, чтобы избежать повторных запросов одних и тех же параметров
    var height = $('.wp-post-image').eq(i).height() + heighth3; //искомая высота
    if (height != 346) {
       console.log(height);
       console.log(heighth3);
     }
   });
```

Comment: нет, по прежнему какую-то ерунду выводит. не понимаю - и как вы ищите по .text() высоту heighth3?

Comment: Да, это уже под вечер - перенес строку, не посмотрев, что там text() на конце а не height() (название переменной heighth3 сбило с толку). Сейчас подправлю

Comment: Что до остального,  попробуй запустить такую штуку  `$('.wp-post-image').each(function(i) {  console.log(  $('.product-section h3').eq(i).height()+$('.wp-post-image').eq(i).height() ); });` и посмотреть, что выдаст консоль - может это наведет тебя на какю-нибудь мысль

Comment: да, спасибо @Grinya Lesnoy, разобрался 
готовый ответ в моем случае: ` $('.main-product .thumbnail-container').each(function(i) {  
 var height = $('.main-product .product-section h3').eq(i).height()+$('.main-product .thumbnail-container').eq(i).height();
 if (height != 346) {
  $('.main-product .product-frame .price').eq(i).css("top",(height+32)+"px");
    }
 });`